# Dynamically set height for Material-UI dropdown menu?

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui

I'm using a custom popover style to create a mega-menu with Material-UI in my React project. The style looks like this:

```
root: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1.5),
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      display: 'none',
    },
  },
popoverPaper: {
  width: '90%',
  height: '80%',
  maxHeight: 'unset',
  left: '5% !important',
},
paper: {
  padding: theme.spacing(2),
  textAlign: 'center',
  color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
},
```

Then I apply this custom CSS to my `Menu` component like so:

```
<Menu
  id="customized-menu"
  className={classes.root}
  anchorEl={blogMenuAnchorEl}
  anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'bottom' }}
  transformOrigin={{ vertical: 'top' }}
  getContentAnchorEl={null}
  open={blogMenu}
  onClose={closeBlogDropDown}
  PopoverClasses={{ paper: classes.popoverPaper }}
>
```

This works as expected. However, I don't want to hard-code the *height* attribute and want it to expand/contract depending on the amount of elements it contains. I tried doing away with `height: 80%`, but that introduces a vertical scrollbar to my drop-down. Is there any way to achieve this? I want to display the contents of `Menu` in entirety, without introducing scrollbars.

**Additional info**: Here's what the menu currently looks like (note the vertical scrollbar; that's what I want to lose):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change PopoverPaper height to 'max-content', that should do it.

```
popoverPaper: {
  width: '90%',
  height: 'max-content', //change here
  maxHeight: 'unset',
  left: '5% !important',
},
```

Comment: The vertical scrollbar remains. Am posting a screenshot in the question.

Comment: can you post your classes.root styles? className={classes.root}

Comment: Added it to the question

Comment: I think the problem is caused by other styles, because I couldn't reproduce it with the styles in the question. Do you use Material-Ui ThemeProvider in your app?

Comment: Strange. Because what I've posted is the entirety of the stype definition for this component. I don't have even an custom external stye definition for it!